# Redirect to same page but add dynamic route

Tags: flask, url, routes

I'm building a webapp where you can add Player-Profiles into a table to compare these. I've posted all changes to same URL, now I found out that the changes are seen by all users.

I considered how to fix this: Instead of url .../stats I tried to individualize url for every Profile added to the table like `.../stats?id=237` (for one profile) `.../stats?id=237id=335` (for two profiles).

Method for the stats:

```
@app.route('/stats/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def pstats():
    ...
    ...
    urla= [237, 335]
    return redirect(url_for('pstats', data = urla ))
```

1. route: `.../stats`
   [image]
2. route: `.../stats?id=237`
   [image]
3. route: `.../stats?id=237id=335`
   [image]

How can I write the route of `pstats` dynamically that it can look like 1. route or 2. route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `request.args` to get the query parameters that are passed to your route.

```py
@app.route('/stats/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def pstats():
    id = request.args['id']
```

Pass `id` to `url_for` to generate a URL that contains query parameters.

```py
url_for(url_for('pstats', id=id))
```